# Splashing water in football

Tags: rules, football

I recently came across a video in which players were playing football in a heavily water logged pitch. It makes me wonder if players are allowed to take advantage of this by kick a puddle (like a fake shot) and attempt to splash water on the defender/attacker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the referee has not abandoned the game for unplayable conditions, this is certainly a cautionable offence as unsporting behaviour (USB) under law 12.3.